# Build failed due to error in CLEErrorDomain.h

Tags: xcode, core-location

I'm getting an odd error in line 18 of the CLErrorDomain.h under CoreLocation.framework.

The line is

```
extern NSString *const kCLErrorDomain;
```

and there is an error for "Expected identifier or "("

I haven't messed with this file at all, and it's locked anyways so it would be difficult to change. Why is this error coming up, and what can I do to get rid of it?

I've tried restarting xCode, cleaning my project and taking CoreLocation out of my project and putting it back in.

Thanks

Comment: Also, my other projects that use corelocation are still working fine.

Comment: I've tried removing core location from the build phases, and the project itself, but the error still shows up. I've also tried resetting my mac.

Comment: Alright, I commented out that line of code, now the error has moved to the CLError.h on the first line of real code, so this is making me think the problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the issue ended up not being in the CLErrorDomain.h

While looking at the error log, I noticed it was erroring out when it tried to compile the main.m... at the very top of the main.m file there was a stray "^" mark before any of the code and that was what was causing the error.